# Subversion for Shell-Script management in a Datacenter Environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, svn

i work as a datacenter administrator with a ton of linux servers and we have about 200 shell scripts to manage applications and systems. At the moment we use RCS as versioning for our scripts but as our DC team is getting larger and larger this is no longer a usable way to go. I thought about SVN to centralise this and keep track of changes, my plan is to do this as following:

One Repository called "DC" with a subfolder for every script/program in trunk, all admins do their changes in  trunk and check in/out the single folders containing the scripts.

One branch named "testing", if a change is done and ready to test, users have to export the subfolder to "testing", our testing environment will automatically download the HEAD revision of the scripts from the testing branch via cronjobs.

A second branch called "stable", if the scripts are tested, the user have to move the script from "testing" to "stable" where all productive servers update the scripts periodically via cronjob from the "stable" branch.

I'm rather new to SVN and want to know if this is a possible way to go?
How do you guys use SVN as a VCS for Shell Scripts, AFAIK i can not work with single files in SVN, that's why i use a subfolder for every shell script named same as the script without the .sh extension. One Repo for every script would be some kind of overkill IMO, people would have to check in/out multiple repos, switch between them and so on.

Kind Regards

Comment: Why such a rigid separation of scripts? You could group them according to type (cron/manual) and/or what type of job they refer to (install/housekeeping) and/or the application they are used for?

Comment: At the end all scripts are in /usr/local/dc/bin without a folder hierarchy, so they are not sorted at all. I thought about this subfolder-system because AFAIK i can't commit or checkout single states of files, only on directories and their content, so if one admin is working on a reorganisation script for databases and a second one on a backup statistic script ,they will get into conflicts if scripts are in the same folder at a commit. But i could be totally wrong with this assumption.

Comment: As far as I understand you are wrong. Sure you can commit or checkout single files and their content independent from other files in the same directory. Only when moving them it get a bit more hairy.

Comment: Suggestion: write some minimal shell scripts into the question and show what you expect the VCS subversion to yield in conflict cases. THat would match more the coder focus of this site. How did you handles previously shared core script updates with RCS? Say pf.sh is used in N other scripts, one of them needs a change in pf.sh output, that conflicts with what one or more other client scripts depend on. If you know how to resolve these conflicts, unroll into meaningfull usable actions for the admins / coders, you should have your VCS idea "good nuff". SVN is centralized. Ok in your use case?

Comment: I only have two scripts depending on other scripts. All other scripts are useable standalone. So AFAIK we never had problems with "core components". I know that this is not a best practice but i'm in this company for only 7 months and we still use old scripts from HP UX environments on RHEL now with creation dates back to 1996....
The RCS way was: Do the change, copy via scp onto producitve, no real testing only if the admin was eager to do it himself.
My aim is to bring a little bit of order into this choas :)